# add event listener is not a function with queryselector

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have error stating addeventlistener is not a function but when i remove innerhtml it seems to work

```
 var num1 = document.querySelector('.num1').innerHTML;
 var num2 = document.querySelector('.num2').innerHTML;


 num1.addEventListener('click',function num() {

    console.log('working');

})


<button class="num1">1</button>
<button class="num2">2</button>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` returns a string not a dom node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a string [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> ...contains the **serialized** HTML code describing all of the element's
>   descendants.

If you want to set event listeners you need to get DOM node

```
var num1 = document.querySelector('.num1')
```

Comment: how do i select the value 1 inside the button

Comment: @AkashDikkaram `var content = num1.innerText` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, the property innerHTML return the html string content. If you wanna add a event, you must do in a NODE element directly.

```js
var num1 = document.querySelector('.num1');
var num2 = document.querySelector('.num2');


num1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('working');
    console.log(num1.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<span class="num1">1</span>
<span class="num2">3</span>
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You cannot add an eventlistener on a string:

Update to:

```
var num1 = document.querySelector('.num1');
 var num2 = document.querySelector('.num2');
 num1.addEventListener('click',function num(e) {
    //if you need the innerHTML value
    console.log(e.target.value)
    console.log('working');

})


<button class="num1">1</button>
<button class="num2">2</button>
```